# Count number of comparisons of a sorting algorithm and add it to an array list in java

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

Hi I have a generic bubble sort algorithm which I am using and I want to track the number of comparisons that occur before the array is sorted. The number of comparisons must be stored in an array list. I am not too sure how to do this so I was wondering if anyone can help. Thanks

```
protected static ArrayList<Integer> noOfComparisons = new ArrayList<Integer>();

public static <E extends Comparable<? super E>> void bubbleSort(E[] comparable) {
boolean changed = false;
do {
    changed = false;
    for (int a = 0; a < comparable.length - 1; a++) {
        if (comparable[a].compareTo(comparable[a + 1]) > 0) {
            E tmp = comparable[a];
            comparable[a] = comparable[a + 1];
            comparable[a + 1] = tmp;
            changed = true;
        }
    }
} while (changed);
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what the ArrayList should contain -- the number of comparisons for the whole sort?  the number of comparisons made to the element at the corresponding index?

Comment: why do you need to store the number of comparisons in an `ArrayList`, if like you said it's a "number" of comparisons, you should be able to store it in a number, of say type `int`

Comment: Why would you store it in an `ArrayList` instead of just an `int`?  Is this homework?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: Is this homework?  If so, please add the "homework" tag to your question.

Comment: I will be making a graph and one of the axis will have the number of comparisons, so I will have to store each number at the corresponding index

Comment: Do you want to store the number of times *each* element is involved in a comparison?

Comment: @Treebranch I had not really planned for that but now thinking of it, I think that would be a better requirement. If thats not really a good option then just number of comparisons

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to keep track of the number of comparisons every time you sort an array. To do so, create an `int` initialized at zero at the beginning of the bubbleSort method, and then increase that number whenever a comparison is performed. At the end of your bubbleSort method, add that int to the list.

Comment: Nice answer, i have tried to create an equation for that but i'm stuck with it... it turns out that basing only on the array it not so easy to determine how many operation would be need to sort it.

Comment: right, also the question was more along the lines of *counting* the number of comparisons performed, not so much *predicting* that number based on an array, which would be more complicated.

Comment: I know, that equation was just for entertain, and as a response for question that is really easy when someone know how the algorithm works. But it turn out to be really nice mathematical problem to solve. That if it would be possible in O(n) time to figure out how many operation do we need to sort an array using bubble sort.